# Resume Downloading without delay when application is killed

Tags: android, service, retrofit2, android-download-manager

I'm using Retrofit to download files from server,and showing progress in notification bar,it is working fine.But the issue is that i want to keep the downloading process smooth, when user kills the application then i restart the downloading service using START_REDELIVER_INTENT , but it takes long time to restart the service for downloading. How can i tackle this issue? and is there any way to resume the download instead of restarting it? I know about sending If-Range parameter in header but how can it be used in Retrofit request? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: make persistent service class

Comment: Thanks @Divyesh for showing a direction, will it be stoppable by stopSelf() method?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Persistent service is for system apps only,seems to be deprecated.But startForeground worked for me.